# R loop to create data frames with 2 counters

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop

What I want is to create 60 data frames with 500 rows in each. I tried the below code and, while I get no errors, I am not getting the data frames. However, when I do a View on the as.data.frame, I get the view, but no data frame in my environment. I've been trying for three days with various versions of this code:

```
getDS <- function(x){
  for(i in 1:3){
    for(j in 1:30000){
      ID_i <- data.table(x$ID[j: (j+500)])
    }
  }
  as.data.frame(ID_i)
}

getDS(DATASETNAME)
```

Comment: If it is 60 dataframes, the `j` index should be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the description matches the code, so I'm a little unsure what the desired result is. That said, it is usually not helpful to split a `data.table` because the built-in by-processing makes it unnecessary. If for some reason you do want to split into a list of `data.table`s you might consider something along the lines of

```
getDS <- function(x, n=5, size = nrow(x)/n, column = "ID", reps = 3) {
    x <- x[1:(n*size), ..column]
    index <- rep(1:n, each = size) 
    replicate(reps, split(x, index),
              simplify = FALSE)
}

getDS(data.table(ID = 1:20), n = 5)
```

Comment: Thanks @Ista. I'm getting an error about column not being found:                         
  Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object '..column' not found

Comment: @Divs you probably have an old version of `data.table`. Update to the latest release (currently `1.11.8`).

Answer (score 2):

We can use `outer` (on a small example)

```
out1 <- c(outer(1:3, 1:3, Vectorize(function(i, j) list(x$ID[j:(j + 5)]))))
lapply(out1, as.data.table)
```

--

The issue in the OP's function is that inside the loop, the `ID_i` gets updated each time i.e. it is not stored.  Inorder to do that we can initialize a `list` and then store it

```
getDS <- function(x) {
      ID_i <- vector('list', 3)
      for(i in 1:3) {
           for(j in 1:3) {
           ID_i[[i]][[j]] <- data.table(x$ID[j:(j + 5)])
          }
        }
      ID_i
    }

do.call(c, getDS(x))
```

#### data

```
x <- data.table(ID = 1:50)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @akrun!!

Comment: I'm getting the lists, but not sure how to unpack them into different dataframes.

Comment: @Divs. It is better to keep it in a `list` instead of creating different objects in the global environment.  But, if you want to have different objects (not recommended). `lst1 <- do.call(c, getDS(x)); names(lst1) <- paste0("data", seq_along(lst1)); list2env(lst1, envir = .GlobalEnv)`. Now you can check `data1`, `data2` on your global env.  But, as I said, it is easier to work with `list`s of data.frame

Comment: Thanks @akrun. The reason I want them as dataframes is because I need to write.csv() on them.